# Xcode 6.2の分散ビルド

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Xcode 6.2で、複数台のMacでの分散ビルドを行いたいのですが、どこから設定できるでしょうか。
（昔はXcodeのPreferencesにあったのですが…）

Comment: これです
http://www.slideshare.net/nnkgw/xcode-7718473

Answer (score 4, accepted):

分散ビルドの機能はXcode 4.3から無くなりました。将来的に復活する可能性はありますが、少なくともXcode 5〜6.3にはその設定は存在しません。